# Strange noise when holding MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I recently bought a MacBook Pro Retina and for now I'm a little bit worried. Everytime I hold it up by one of its edges or even press this part (video), it makes this strange noise, like its gonna break. I thought the material was resistant. 
I'm pressing the downside of the notebook, like at the start of the notebook. Downside, of course. If I hold the notebook to get it by this particular corner it also makes this strange noise. I'm a little worried. 
Should I take it to an Apple Store?

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tp6tu70yzwdga12/V%C3%ADdeo%2001-04-15%2001%2051%2014.mov?dl=0) is a video with the strange sound!

Picture of the exact corner:

[image]

[image]

Comment: is that at the back of the laptop? If so then that is fairly normal as there are gaps between the top and bottom of the casing to allow for airflow and also this is where the speaker sound comes from

Comment: Did you already check if it is the cooling fan (check ifixit.com for an "exploded view" of your RetMBP)?

Comment: Echoing @mitchellD. I have a late 2013 rMBP (same form factor). **This is normal.**  Not airflow (heat dissipates through the back), but indeed there’s a gap between the screen and the keyboard/surrounding area. If you look at the outer bezel, you will notice the aluminum lining is raised 1 mm - meant to prevent the screen from chafing.

Comment: @MitchellD Hi everyone. Thanks for the answers. I was too tired and ended up saying some things wrong. The part when it makes this noise is on the <b>opposite</b> side of the part where the screen touches the "case". So, it's like on the start. Thanks!!

Comment: I added some pictures to the post

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem where is sounded like a "click" when pressing on the area you described. This was quite annoying while typing.

To resolve this I added a little bit of sewing oil to the screws and edges of the case where it makes the noise.

1. Press on the area where it does make a sound
2. Add a little drop of sewing oil (not too much) to the screws and edges
3. Press a few times times.
4. Wipe it the excesses and check if the noise is gone